# Two definitions of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I remember that I've ever seen these two definitions of convergence somewhere:

1. A sequence $S_n$ converges to $s$ iff $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}, \exists N$ such that $\forall n>N,|S_n-s|<\frac{1}{m}$
2. A sequence $S_n$ converges to $s$ iff $\forall r\in\mathbb{R}>0, \exists N$ such that $\forall n>N,|S_n-s|<r$.

My question is whether in reals those two definitions are equivalent or not? I suppose they are, but I am just not sure about the proof. Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried to prove it? What difficulties did you come across, if so? If not, why not think about it a bit and let us know what you think about it?

Comment: Both are equivalents. Both can be deducted from the original definition of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) to 1) is clear. Now assume that 1) holds, for every $r>0$, we find a large $m\in{\bf{N}}$ such that $1/m<r$, and by 1), we have something like $|S_{n}-s|<1/m<r$, so $|S_{n}-s|<r$ is then established.

Comment: Why has it to be large? Is this proof hold by assuming that $0<r<1$? Cheers!

Comment: Say, $r=0.123456789$, I think you better come with $m=1000000000000$. Yes, the statement is true if we restrict to $0<r<1$.

Comment: Ok cool! Oh and is the existence of that large $m\in\mathbb{N}$ implied by Archimedean property of reals?

Comment: Yes, Archimedean is the crucial property.

Answer (score 1):

Let's show that

i) $\forall m\in\mathbb{N^*}, \exists N \in \mathbb{N^*},\forall n>N,|S_n-s|<\frac{1}{m}$

and

ii) $\forall r >0, \exists N  \in \mathbb{N^*}, \forall n>N,|S_n-s|<r$

are equivalent.

No problem showing ii) implies i).

Now suppose i). Let $r>0$. There exists an $m \in \mathbb{N^*}$ such that $\frac{1}{m} < r$.
There also exists $N$ such that $\forall n>N,|S_n-s|<\frac{1}{m}$.

Hence $\forall n>N,|S_n-s|< r$.

Hence i).

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{N}^*$? Is it hypernatural numbers? Also does this proof assume that $0<r<1$? Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: Huh I don't know, $\mathbb{N^*}$ just means that I choose a stricly positive integer (I don't want to divide by 0). Maybe french notation here. I don't suppose that $0 < r < 1$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are equivalent, basically because $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$. For a rigorous justification of this, see the Archimidean property of the reals.